# Como puedo armar una funcion predicado cuando tengo que elegir entre varios opciones

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una clase

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int? a { get; set; }
    public int? b { get; set; }

    public TestClass(int _a, int _b)
    {
        a = _a;
        b = _b;
    }
}
```

Y para esta clase, genero una lista con elementos de la misma.

```
List<TestClass> lista = new List<TestClass>
{
    new TestClass(1,2),
    new TestClass(2,3),
    new TestClass(1,3)
};
```

Ahora, me gustaria generar un metodo que segun las opciones que me selecciona el usuario, me permita devolver o todos los elementos de la lista (si no selecciono nada), o aquellos que cumplen con lo que selecciono el usuario.

Si tengo esa clase con solo esas dos propiedades podria hacer algo asi:

```
List<TestClass> resul;
if (seleccionA == null && seleccionB == null)
{
    resul = lista;
}
if (seleccionA == null && seleccionB != null)
{
    resul = lista.Where(v => seleccionB == v.b).ToList();
}
if (seleccionA != null && seleccionB == null)
{
    resul = lista.Where(v => seleccionA == v.a).ToList();
}
if (seleccionA != null && seleccionB != null)
{
    resul = lista.Where(v => seleccionA == v.a && seleccionB == v.b).ToList();
}
```

Pero si fueran mas de dos propiedades, el if es cada vez peor. Como puedo solucionar esto de una forma mas eficiente de escribir en el codigo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para estos casos podemos hacer uso de las funciones anonimas y construir un predicado que vaya cambiando depende las opciones seleccionadas.

Para ello, vamos a definir lo siguiente:

```
Func<TestClass, bool> predicate = null;

void ArmarPredicado(Func<TestClass, bool> newPredicate)
{
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        predicate = newPredicate;
        return;
    }
    var oldPredicate = predicate;
    predicate = s => oldPredicate(s) && newPredicate(s);
}
```

Y ahora, por cada valor que querramos que se agregue (o no) al predicado vamos a hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (valora != null)
{
    ArmarPredicado(v => (valora == v.a));
}
```

Y vamos a escribir una funcion para analizar el predicado y devolver la lista necesaria:

```
List<TestClass> DevolverLista(List<TestClass> lista, Func<TestClass, bool> predicate)
{
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        return lista;
    }
    return lista.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

De esta forma, si tenemos que agregar mas condiciones, solo tenemos que agregarla al predicado que estamos construyendo.

---

ArmarPredicado es una funcion anonima, que devuelve justamente lo que necesita el where, que es una condición y el valor que va a retornar la misma.

Cuando le pasamos `v => (valora == v.a)`, transforma eso a otra funcion anonima, y va concatenando esas funciones.

Como dice la definición de where

```
Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)
```

la misma recibe una Func<,>, que es justamente lo que nosotros declaramos como predicate. y lo otro que hicimos, fue ir concatenando las mismas segun la necesidad.

Comment: Por que te contestaste tu mismo?

Comment: @Michelle si miras como funciona el sitio, es totalmente valido, esta permitido y hasta se recomienda. En este caso surgio la duda en el [chat] y entonces para compartir el conocimiento escribi la pregunta (quien la iba a escribir no puedo hacerlo) y la conteste, ya que sabia la respuesta. Eso no implica que alguien pueda hacer una respuesta mejor.

Comment: Ah que bien, yo pensé que habías hecho esto porque estabas muy aburrido y sin nada que hacer, y por tanto escribías tus preguntas y tu mismo las respondias.. :P

Comment: perdonen este comentario fuera de contexto pero me ha dado demasiada risa leer "yo pensé que habías hecho esto porque estabas muy aburrido y sin nada que hacer, y por tanto escribías tus preguntas y tu mismo las respondias.. :P" xD!!!!!!!!! HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: @Michelle Ese es el estilo de StackOverflow, compartir conocimiento :D

Comment: ¿Y no es mejor hacerlo con expresiones? por ejemplo: "Func<TestClass, bool> ArmarPredicado(params Expression<TestClass, object>[] exp)" y de esa forma lo puedes invocar así: var predicado = ArmarPredicado(x => x.A, x => x.B, x => x.OtraPropiedad);

Comment: @Luis Y si una de esas es null como evitas mandarla?

Comment: @gbianchi dentro del método ArmarPredicado puedes compilar cada una de las expresiones y con eso crear la función. Deja veo si puedo agregar una respuesta con un ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

aquí va mi respuesta usando expresiones:

Primero importamos los siguientes namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

Luego, recomiendo también crear un alias para este tipo:

```
using Exp = Tuple<object, Expression<Func<TestClass, object>>>;
```

Y el método ArmarPredicado quearía así:

```
Func<TestClass, bool> ArmarPredicado(params Exp[] exp)
{
    Func<TestClass, bool> result = null;
    foreach(var item in exp) {
        if (item.Item1 != null) {
            var compiled = item.Item2.Compile();
            Func<TestClass, bool> oldPredicate = result;
            Func<TestClass, bool> newPredicate = s => item.Item1.Equals(compiled.Invoke(s));
            if (oldPredicate == null) {
                result = newPredicate;
            }
            else {
                result = s => newPredicate(s) && oldPredicate(s);
            }
        }
    }
    return result ?? (x => true);
}
```

Y lo utilizas así:

```
var filtro = ArmarPredicado(
    new Exp(valora, x => x.a),
    new Exp(valorb, x => x.b));

List<TestClass> resul = lista.Where(filtro).ToList();
```

Si valora y valorb son null, te regresa toda la lista source, y sino, crea el filtro con los que no sean null.

De esta forma no tienes que crar el predicado con if's, una sola línea te crea el predicado, solo pasas el par de objetos que es, el que contiene el valor que vas a filtrar, y la expresión que indica con cuál propiedad se va a comparar el objeto.

Y como pasas un arreglo con formato params, puedes agregar todos los pares "filtro -> propiedad" que requieras.

Con C# 7 y el tipo ValueTuple queda incluso mejor.

EDIT: Lo único malo es que solo es por igualdad, es decir, solo verifica si son iguales, un filtro mas estructurado no vale, aunque eso se puede solucionar.

EDIT: Una idea para que se pueda crear con cualquier expresión, no solo igualdad:

```
var predicate = new PredicateBuilder()
    .Add(valora, x => x.a, (x, y) => x == y)
    .Add(valorb, x => x.b, (x, y) => x > y)
    .Build();

List<TestClass> result = predicate == null 
    ? lista 
    : lista.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Si te interesa puedo crear la clase y editar y ponerla.

Comment: Es una buena solucion.Como vos decis solo funciona por iguales. Entiendo tu problema con los if, pero tampoco veo que pasa si filtro es nulo (o sea no hay ninguna condicion si no que hay que devolver toda la lista). Filtro no viene como null en ese caso?

Comment: Si son 10 condiciones las agregas así: var filtro = ArmarPredicado(new Exp(valor1, x => x.Prop1), new Exp(valor2, x => x.Prop2), new Exp(valor3, x => x,Prop3, ...., new Exp(valor10, x => x.Prop10)); filtro nunca va a ser nulo, si te fijas al final del método ArmarPredicado devuelvo esto: return result ?? (x => true); si todos valores son nul (por ejemplo valora y valorb), va a devolver la función x => true, que en el Where de la lista iimplica poner lista.Where(x => true), que obviamente se trae todos los datos.

Comment: En cuanto a lo de que solo funciona con igualdad, se puede modificar para que acepte cualquier condición.

Comment: Me gusta... igual me gustaria ver como seria si no fueran solamente iguales (otro tipo de condiciones, cualesquiera) y tambien, si ese x=>true no implica recorrer innecesariamente toda la lista....

Comment: Para poder hacerlo para cualquier expresión no solo de igualdad, habría que hacer una clase que se encargue de crear la función filtro, y tendría un método "Add" que agregaría el valor, la expresión que indica la propiedad con la que se va a comparar el valor, y la expresión que se usará para comparar, algo así: var predicate = new PredicateBuilder().Add(valora, x => x.a, (x, y) => x ==  y).Add(valorb, x => x.b, (x, y) => x > y).Build(); En cuanto a lo otro, igual se puede regresar null y solo haces: List<TestClass> resul = predicate == null ? lista : lista.Where(predicate).ToList();

Comment: yo lo veo mas complicado de entender para un monton de valores (esto fue un ejemplo y salio de una conversacion en el chat). Si tenes ganas d eponer un ejemplo genial. Para expresiones simples esto funciona mejor que la otra respuesta.