# Filtros dinamicos en consulta linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql

necesito realizar una consulta a una base de datos Sql Server, esta debe retornar el stock de los artículos recibidos como parámetro filtrando por código y color de articulo.

Mi forma de plantearlo ha sido mas o menos así:

```
public async List<Stock> StockArticulos(List<CArticle>articulos)
{
    List<Stock> result = new List<Stock>();
    foreach(CArticle art in articulos)
    {
        List<Stock> temp = await _context.StockWeb.Where(x => x.Codigoarticulo == art.CodigoArticulo.Trim() && x.Codigocolor_ == art.CodigoColor_.Trim()).Select(y => new Stock
        {
            CodigoArticulo = y.Codigoarticulo,
            CodigoColor_ = y.Codigocolor_,
            Pendienterecibir = y.Pendienterecibir,

            stock = Convert.ToDecimal(y.Unidades)
        }).ToListAsync();
        result.AddRange(temp);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Esto debería funcionar, pero parece poco eficiente.
Mi pregunta es, si hay alguna manera para generar el filtro concatenando el `where` y tantos `AND` y `OR` como parámetros me lleguen y aplicarlo a la consulta Linq.

Muchas gracias.

**EDIT:**
Estoy usando Entity Framework Core 5.0

**EDIT2:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Stock>>>GetLista([FromBody] List<CArticle> filtres)
{
    List<Func<StockWeb, bool>> filtre = new List<Func<StockWeb, bool>>();
    List<Stock> stock = new List<Stock>();
    foreach (CArticle article in filtres)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(article.CodigoArticulo) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(article.CodigoColor_))
        {
            filtre.Add(x => x.Codigoarticulo == article.CodigoArticulo && x.Codigocolor_ == article.CodigoColor_);
        }
    }
    stock = _context.StockWeb.Where(filtre);

}
```

Esto me genera este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me deja añadir mas código, añado imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí se puede, se necesitan Delegados

Comment: Si, estoy probando con ello, Pero no veo como puedo especificar el tipo de condicional de cada filtro ni como asignar esta lista de filtros a la consulta, elimino el codigo porque queda fatal.
Lo que hago es llenar una  `List<Func<CArticle, bool>>`  para luego asignarlos al _`context.StockWeb.Where(filtros)` pero no me funciona, dejando de lado que no se especificar si el siguiente filtro será un AND o un OR

Comment: Agrega todo lo que hayas intentado en la pregunta :D

Comment: Agrega también la definición de tus clases, en este caso CArticle y Stock.

Comment: Pantallazos < Código. Escribe el código en lugar de los pantallazos por favor, es más fácil recibir ayuda de ese modo puesto que es copiar/pegar.

Comment: Añadí capturas porque no me dejaba pegar el editor no permitía pegar más código, lo siento.

Comment: esta pregunta no es lo que estas preguntando? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/182584/324

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema aquí es de logica:

1. si deseas que la funcion tome filtros de Manera dinámica incluso un numero indeterminado entonces deberías pasarle a tu funcion un Array con los filtros a aplicar.
2. Una vez en el metodo de la consulta, iteras el array de los filtros; concatenando cada filtro a la consulta original:

El pseudo código de ejemplo seria así:

```
var consulta = Consulta sin filtros;
var Filtros = [Filtro 1, Filtro 2, Filtro 3, ....]

Metodo dinamico(consulta, Filtros ){

    foreach (Filtros as Filtro){
        var consulta += agregar/concatenar los filtro a la consulta.
    }

    Finalizar la construccion de la consulta si se requiere

    var resultados = Realizar consulta a la base de datos.

    retornar resultados;

}
```

de esta manera no existe un limite de filtros... y el armado es dinámico...

esta lógica se emplea tambien en esta respuesta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/182586/46896

Answer (score 0):

Considerando la limitación de los datos en la pregunta, básicamente tendrías algo como esto:

```
Func<CArticle, bool> filtroDinamico1 = x => x.Codigoarticulo == art.CodigoArticulo.Trim(); 
Func<CArticle, bool> filtroDinamico2 = x => x.Codigocolor_ == art.CodigoColor_.Trim();
Func<CArticle, bool> filtroDinamico3 = x => x.Codigoarticulo == art.CodigoArticulo.Trim() && x.Codigocolor_ == art.CodigoColor_.Trim();

public async List<Stock> StockArticulos(List<CArticle> articulos, Func<CArticle, bool> filtro)
{
    List<Stock> result = new List<Stock>();
    foreach (CArticle art in articulos)
    {
        List<Stock> temp = await _context.StockWeb.Where(filtro).Select(y => new Stock
        {
            CodigoArticulo = y.Codigoarticulo,
            CodigoColor_ = y.Codigocolor_,
            Pendienterecibir = y.Pendienterecibir,

            stock = Convert.ToDecimal(y.Unidades)
        }).ToListAsync();
        result.AddRange(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

var test1 = await StockArticulos(listaArticulos, filtroDinamico1);
var test2 = await StockArticulos(listaArticulos, filtroDinamico2);
var test3 = await StockArticulos(listaArticulos, filtroDinamico3);
```

Comment: No entiendo, según tu ejemplo, estamos haciendo una consulta a la base de datos por cada uno de los artículos que recibo.
Yo lo que pretendía era hacer una sola consulta con where filtro1, and filtro2 ....and filtroN

Comment: Según el ejemplo, puedes incluir cualquier tipo de filtro dentro del `WHERE`. Cosa que lo definas, en este caso hice 3 filtros para que veas cómo es la situación

Comment: SI, pero lo que no se como hacer, es construir un único filtro con todos los artículos a consultar, es decir, por cada iteración de la lista de artículos a consultar, "concatenar" ese 'OR' al filtro, para pasarle un único filtro a la consulta con todos los artículos a consultar.

Comment: A este punto, no entiendo, hay un único filtro en la respuesta... dependiendo de lo que le pases. ¿Podrías incluir en tu pregunta un ejemplo en pseudo código con alguna lista de datos y una simulación de la ejecución de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿conoces sobre Delegados?

Comment: creo que el compa quiere pasar los filtros mediante un array de filtros y meterlos en un bucle esto soportaria filtros indefinidos... dentro del bucle puede concatenar los filtros de Manera Dinamica a la consulta original...